# Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on a separate physical drive

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot

I have Windows 10 installed on one physical drive and I want to be able to install Ubuntu on the second one but in such a way that I will be able to choose the operating system while the computer boots.

The manuals I found in the internet were not clear enough and I did not want to take "risks" because I need this computer up and running.

What is the correct way of doing so?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Install it along with Windows and you'll get GRUB installed as well so you can choose the OS you want.

Comment: For more accurate guidance add an image of your current partition state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many other options that can be changed during installation for different reasons and it is not possible to mention them all so it's just a basic guide 
And sorry for bad English!!!

1. Create a live USB of Ubuntu using [rufus](https://rufus.ie) on Windows
2. Boot live USB ( change boot order if needed ) and select try Ubuntu  (or you can select install Ubuntu your choice ) and start the installer
3. Follow this guide now :https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 
   with following changes

> ```
> Installation type
>
> choose the 'Something else' option.
>
> Click on the desired partition ( on which you want to install Ubuntu )and press the change button
>
>
>  - choose ext4file system, and mount point as / (i.e. root)
>
>  Select the format box for the partition you selected
> ```

Create swap partition.To create a swap first select the partition to be used as swap and press configure button .From there set

```
 - use as option to swap area and partition type as Logical partition
```

It is advised by many that swap should be double of your system’s RAM size.

```
Note for “Device for boot loader installation” :

For example if you are installing Ubuntu with sdb3 as root partition then select the whole disk i.e sdb for bootloader installation ; if sda2 is the disk on which you are installing then select sda for bootloader installation.
```

Click on install to start the installation and once done ,then boot from drive and you should get grub screen asking for which is Operating system to boot.

If something not clear or if things are missed out then will surely edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the tutorial here https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/ .

But instead when you are making a partition in step 3, choose whichever drive you want (e.g. make space on hdd instead if sdd). Then in step 6 when creating a partition choose the partition you created on this other drive. The rest should work the same.

Consider if you really want to install all Ubuntu on a separate drive. I am also using a dual boot and I have mounted my root folder `/` in my sdd and my `/home` folder in my hdd so that i didn't run out of space.
To do this create two partitions in step 3: one on sdd (I have around 20-25GB) and one on hdd (50+GB). Then in step 6 when you are creating partitions, first create swap partition on sdd. Then create another partition on sdd and select mount point `/`. Lastly, create a partition on hdd and select mount point `/home`.
This is also explained in the link above.